# Django tests are not working but views do

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm trying to test to insert data into db to test if My views are working.
What could i do to see what's happening inside the page?

I've one error, when i try to assert if data that I've sent to My form exists.

The stranger thing is that when i run My application with runserver, everything works fine, but when i'm in test, the view doesn't work.

```py
     def test_new_board_creation_view(self):
        url = reverse('new_board')
        response = self.client.get(url)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.resolver_match.func, new_board_creation_view)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'new_board.html')

        url = reverse('new_board')
        form = {'board_name': 'board_di_prova.....',}

        response = self.client.post(url, {'form': form})
        self.assertTrue(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertEqual(Board.object.count(), 4)
        
        response = reverse('board_view', args=(Board.object.last().id,))
        self.assertTrue(response, 200)
```

views.py

```py
    def new_board_creation_view(request):
    title = 'AGGIUNGI BOARD'
    form = BoardCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BoardCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
            nb = Board_id_user(board_id=form.id, user_id=request.user.id)
            print(nb)
            nb.save()

            return redirect('/dashboard/')
        else:
            form = BoardCreationForm()
            return render(request, 'new_board.html', {'form': form, 'title': title})
    else:
        form = BoardCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'new_board.html', {'form': form, 'title': title})
```

I expect that count 5 objects because 4 are present, but the insert fails and then, to make test pass, i do assert 4...

Comment: What do you mean by "tests are not working" ?

Comment: When i use runserver, everything is good. In this view i use a form to insert data. And this save correctly.
With test are not working i mean that i call my view to do something (for example create an object  using a form and insert it into a database). If i do this with runserver it works. When i do this in test, giving manipulated data, when i do assert, test fails...

Comment: post your test function

Comment: @AnaghGoswami code added

Comment: Try - `url = reverse('app_name:new_board')` where `app_name` is the one you defined in the `urls.py` for the app

Comment: It didn't work..

Comment: In this case returns: sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: scrumboard_board_id_user.user_id

Comment: Let's hope this one works. I tested something like this in my app right now and it worked `response = self.client.post(reverse('app_name:new_board'), json.dumps({'board_name': 'board_di_prova.....'}), content_type='application/json')`

Comment: Didn't work... i don't understand why doesn't recognise the user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225481/discussion-between-anagh-goswami-and-federico).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login the client using

```
self.client.force_login(User.objects.get_or_create(username='testuser')[0])
```

For checking status codes do -

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, some-status-code)
```

At some places you have used `assertTrue` rather than `assertEqual`

Do form submission like -

```
form = {'board_name': 'board_di_prova.....'}
response = self.client.post(url, form)
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using the decorator `@pytest.mark.django_db`?
I recommend you set that decorator in your test, so it will have acces to your DB.

Comment: No, i'm not using this decorator. I think i have the access to the database because in the setup i can create new objects...

Comment: He is not using `pytest`